# drawing a square in y and x axes

Tags: tikz-pgf, texmaker

how I can draw this in latex? just here vertices don't look nice I want everything to be nice and in the right place.

[image]

Comment: This can be done very easly with a graphical package as [PGF/TikZ](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf). Read the tutorials on the pgfmanual and try to draw it by yourself, it's fun.

Comment: could you please help me to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a start.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,dot/.style={circle,fill=blue!50,draw=blue,inner
sep=2pt},blue,thick,every label/.style={black}]
 \draw[<->] (-3,0) -- (3,0);
 \draw[<->] (0,-2) -- (0,2);
 \draw (1,0) node[dot,label=above right:{$(1,0)$}] {}
  -- (0,1) node[dot,label=above right:{$(0,1)$}] {}
  -- (-1,0) node[dot,label=above left:{$(-1,0)$}] {}
  -- (0,-1) node[dot,label=below left:{$(0,-1)$}] {} -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility : `tkz-euclide`
It's possible to add style to avoid certain repetitions such as those of colours.

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \tkzInit[xmin=-3,xmax=3,ymin=-3,ymax=3]
  \tkzDrawX[line width=1pt,teal,noticks,<->]
  \tkzDrawY[line width=1pt,teal,noticks,<->]
  \tkzDefPoints{1/0/A,0/1/B,-1/0/C,0/-1/D}
  \tkzDrawPolygon[teal](A,...,D)
  \tkzDrawPoints[teal,fill=teal!30,size=6](A,...,D)
  \tkzLabelPoint[above right,teal](A){$(1,0)$}
  \tkzLabelPoint[above right,teal](B){$(0,1)$}
  \tkzLabelPoint[above left,teal](C){$(-1,0)$}
  \tkzLabelPoint[below left,teal](D){$(0,-1)$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it doesn't have line between vertices in my Mac

Comment: @user9272398 What is your version of `tkz-base` and `tkz-euclide`?

Comment: @user9272398 Do you have change the line `\tkzDrawPolygon[teal](A,...,D)` The only possibility to remove the lines between the vertices is to fill  the polygon, you can try : `\tkzDrawPolygon(A,...,D)`